# show spinner content in a textview

Tags: android, textview, spinner

i want show spinner content in a textview. I can show spinner content in a textview but only show the first element and if ai change the item, the textview dont change

```
    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cbTipoInspeccion);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.tipoPrioridad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);  

    tvMostrar=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerContent);

  String Text = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

    tvMostrar.setText(Text.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an OnItemSelectedListener on your spinner:

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

  onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //update your TextView
    tvMostrar.setText(sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
  }

  onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    //
  }

})
```

Look at the documentation on [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) and [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

Comment: What kind of error? I just updated the code with how to set the value of your TextView. Also, you need to declare your spinner as a global variable in the class.